# jquery php div tag assign

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have this jquery script to assign a div tag with data from a url:

```
$(function() {
  $(".loadlink").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#result").load($(this).data('url'));
  });
});
```

As well as the `#result` div, I want to add another div called `#crimes` which also updates after the one above had ran with data from `page2.php`.

How can I change this to accommodate that extra div?

Answer (score 1):

You can target multiple elements by comma separating them

```
 $("#result, #crimes").load($(this).data('url'));
```

Or if crimes doesn't exist yet...

```
//create an element
var $crimes = $('<div />', {  
     id: 'crimes',
     class: 'myclass'
});

//append the element inside something else 
$('selector').append($crimes);
$("#result, #crimes").load($(this).data('url'));
```

Comment: that'd load the same data for both tags though wouldnt it? whatever 'url' is set as.